# Magmi Import: Not able to set product status to 'Disabled'

Tags: magmi

I am trying to set the status of a set of products to 'Disabled' using magmi import csv. Even though I don't get any error, the product status is not changed in back-end and I am able to see the product in the front-end. I do have stock of these products, so I have retained the attribute 'qty' as a positive value.

What could I be doing wrong? Please guide me - I am new to Magento and magmi.

PS: With the same csv, I am able to set status to 'Enabled', if it was previously 'Disabled' manually from admin panel.

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not post a sample of your CSV file, I'm going to assuming you are using the values `Enabled` and `Disabled` in the `status` column.

This is incorrect, the status attribute requires either:

`1` value for **enabled**
`2` value for **disabled**